# Internet Explorer - Open file dialog with IP address & hostname

Tags: internet-explorer, file-permissions

I am having a static php page with a simple input type file, for file upload.

If I open `http://127.0.0.1/mypage.php` in internet explorer, if I click on it, it opens "open file dialog", but it doesn't show any files in that.

whereas if I open `http://localhost/mypage.php` in internet explorer and click on it, then it opens "open file dialog" and it shows files for selection.

In other browsers, both ways are working fine.

Any idea ? Please help.